# What is this assignment asking me to do, about summing the digits of a value 0425h?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I have this assembly problem where: Given the register AX=0425h. Write a program which adds the sum of digits of value 0425h and stores the sum in the same register AX.
I have no idea what to do in it. Can anyone help me solve this thing?

I tried to think of a solution and did not find anything :)

Comment: Assuming the assignment means hex digits, just chop off 4 bits at a time and add them. Use shifting and masking.

Comment: In this case where the digit-sum doesn't overflow, I think it works to do `imul ax, 0x1111` / `shr ax, 24` (as in the last step of the [popcount bithack](//stackoverflow.com/a/109025)).  But if you need this to work in the general case, e.g. producing a number that might not fit in 4 bits, like for `0xabcd` summing to 46 (0x2e), you'd want to do something like `mov ecx, eax` / `and ax, 0f0fh` / `shr ecx, 4` /  `and cx, 0f0fh` / `add cx, ax` / `add cl, ch` / `movzx eax, cl` to horizontally reduce from 4x 4-bit to 2x 8-bit, then down to one 8-bit and zero-extend.  Or loop like Jester suggested.

Comment: I assume this is 32 or 64-bit code since you tagged Windows.  You might use 32-bit operand-size for `and eax, 0f0fh` and other steps before the final `add cl,ch`; probably equal code-size.

Comment: Let's note that you can solve this in a language like C: it is an algorithm that you want first, then an assembly version.

Comment: Correction to the imul/shr bithack suggestion: `shr ax, 12`, 3 nibbles not 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

> Given the register AX=0425h

The digits of this hexadecimal number are 0, 4, 2, and 5. The assignment wants you to sum these as in 0 + 4 + 2 + 5 = 11.
One possible solution is the following:

```
mov  edx, eax      ;        -> DH=04h  AL=25h
aam  16            ; 25h/16 -> AH=2  AL=5
add  al, ah        ; (5+2)  -> AL=7
xchg al, dh        ;        -> DH=7  AL=04h
aam  16            ; 04h/16 -> AH=0  AL=4
add  al, ah        ; (4+0)  -> AL=4
add  al, dh        ; (4+7)  -> AL=11
cbw                ;        -> AX=11
```

The code works for any value AX=[0000h,FFFFh] producing AX=[0,60].

---

A solution that uses a loop and that can deal with any value EAX=[00000000h,FFFFFFFFh] producing EAX=[0,120]:

```
  xor  ecx, ecx   ; TempResult = 0
More:
  mov  ebx, eax   ; Copy to another temporary register where
  and  ebx, 15    ;   we only keep the lowest digit
  add  ecx, ebx   ; TempResult + LowestDigit
  shr  eax, 4     ; Shift the original digits to the right discarding the one(s) we already added to the TempResult
  jnz  More       ; Only looping if more non-zero digits exist
  mov  eax, ecx   ; EAX = TempResult
```